# How to Connect Remote MySQL Database from Android?

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, http-post, android-webview

I would like to connect my Android App to Remote MySQL database which has WSDL Web service which is only for  authentication. The data push works via HttpPost. Its all in ColdFusion.

I am very new to Android Development and i have searched many tutorials but couldn't find the solution. I would like to know the answers for the following question?

1. How to connect to WSDL Web service for just authentication is Android?
2. How to access the Remote Database using Http Post? (Please if possible post some tutorials)

It will be appreciated if you post some examples or related post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to research on this forum and the web before you post a question. This maybe a possible duplicate: [Android remote MySQL operations using a web service with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508439/android-remote-mysql-operations-using-a-web-service-with-php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have looked at http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database before.. But i had a dought in that.. I think we have to place the PHP file in server side right. The server side is developed usin coldfusion.. Do i need cfm file to access the database.. I am sorry for this simple question.. I am very new to the android development

Comment: You never need to be shy when you do not know something. However, i will advise you take up short courses in web based and mobile programming. The answer to your question is certainly "yes" since PHP is a server-side language.!

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.. Ya i will study more about web based and mobile programming.. The problem here is i didn't have access to the web portal. I am developing a mobile app which want to speak with the web portal in secure way.(i.e getting the data and posting the data into databases). Can you suggest me what i have to ask them regarding the whole process...

Comment: Please go through this tutorial here: http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.com/2011/09/connecting-to-remote-mysql-database.html